# minimum subgraph whose cost is greater than a predefined threshold

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

is there an approximate algorithm that takes as input: an weighted  undirected graph $G = (V,E,W)$ and an integer $k > 0$ and outputting: a subgraph $g'$ with $w(g') \geq k $, and $|g'|$ is minimum. For example

[image]

in this graph, with $k= 65$, the solution is $g'=\{2,4,5 \}$

Comment: If an exact algorithm for this problem existed, it would also solve the NP-hard Clique problem: Put a weight of 1 on every edge in the input graph, and then ask for the smallest subgraph with weight $k(k-1)/2$ -- a clique of size $k$ exists iff the subgraph returned has $k$ vertices.

Comment: No worries, I'm not offended, I was just a bit confused :)  I wish I could give you a better answer for your actual question (which asks for an approximation, not an exact algorithm), but I don't know much about those.  The Clique problem has only terrible polynomial-time approximations unfortunately, which (I think) means that you will not be able to get a very good poly-time approximation for your problem...

Comment: According to Dr. Gautam K. Das Given an optimization problem $P$ , an algorithm $A$ is said to be an
approximation algorithm for $P$, if for any given instance $I$, it returns an approximate solution, that is a feasible solution.